# Javascript: Can't console.log certain objects

Tags: javascript

Having a hard time understanding why some objects won't return properly:

[image]

If I run `console.log(obj.R)` it returns "different", as expected.  If I run `console.log(obj.g)` it just returns `undefined`.  My goal is to return the first value of the `g` object, so something like `console.log(obj.g[0])` and have the value "0.04600" returned.

Full function as requested:

```
function buildCandleStickChart_() {
      CurrencyDataService.getChartData('BTC', vm_.selectedMarket).
          then(function(data) {

            // Set a default theme for the entire chart.
            anychart.theme({
              'defaultFontSettings': {
                'fontSize': 12,
                'fontFamily': 'Roboto'
              }
            });

            var table = anychart.data.table();

            // Map API data to table data.
            dataArray = data.response.map(function(obj) {

              // Format Date
              var formatedDate = moment(obj.time * 1000).format('M-D HH:mm');
              return [formatedDate, obj.open, obj.high, obj.low, obj.close, obj.volumeto];
            });

            // Add API data to table.
            table.addData(dataArray);

            // Map data to candlesticks.
            var mapping = table.mapAs();
            mapping.addField('open', 1, 'first');
            mapping.addField('high', 2, 'max');
            mapping.addField('low', 3, 'min');
            mapping.addField('close', 4, 'last');

            // Map data to volume bars.
            var volMapping = table.mapAs();
            volMapping.addField('value', 5);

            // Get current lowest price.
            var getLowestValue = _.minBy(data.response, 'low');
            lowestLow = getLowestValue.low;
            // Get current highest price.
            var getHighestValue = _.maxBy(data.response, 'high');
            highestHigh = getHighestValue.high;

            // Scale down the volume bars.
            var getHighestVolume = _.maxBy(data.response, 'volumeto');
            var highestVolume = getHighestVolume.volumeto;
            var getLowestVolume = _.minBy(data.response, 'volumeto');
            var lowestVolume = getLowestVolume.volumeto;

            // Initialize the chart.
            var chart = anychart.stock();
            candleStickChartRef = chart;
            candleStickPlotRef = chart.plot(0);

            // Initialize the candlesticks.
            var candleSticks = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping);
            candleSticks.name(vm_.selectedMarket);

            // Toggle chart tooltip
            chart.tooltip(false);

            // Chart Padding
            var padding = chart.padding();
            padding.bottom(0);
            padding.left(0);
            padding.right(88);
            padding.top(0);

            // Chart Margins
            var margin = chart.margin();
            margin.bottom(-1);
            margin.left(0);
            margin.top(-1);
            margin.right(0);

            // Create custom date time scale.
            var dateTimeScale = anychart.scales.dateTime();
            var dateTimeTicks = dateTimeScale.ticks();
            dateTimeTicks.interval(0, 0, 0, 1);

            // Style the X-Axis.
            var xAxis = chart.plot(0).xAxis();
            xAxis.background('#FFFFFF');
            xAxis.height(24);
            xAxis.enabled(true);

            // Adjust axis labels.
            var labels = xAxis.labels();
            labels.format(function(value) {
              var date = new Date(value.tickValue);
              var formattedDate = moment(date).format('MMM DD, HH:mm');
              return formattedDate;
            });
            labels.width(118);

            // Apply date time scale.
            var scale = chart.xScale();
            scale.ticks([{major: {unit: 'minute', count: 15}, minor: {unit: 'second', count: 1}}]);

            // Declare the Y-Axis scale.
            var yScale = chart.plot(0).yScale();

            // Set the position of the Y-Axis values.
            var yAxis = chart.plot(0).yAxis(0);
            yAxis.orientation('right');
            yAxis.drawFirstLabel(true);
            yAxis.drawLastLabel(false);

            // Set the position of the Y-Axis labels.
            var yLabels = chart.plot(0).yAxis().labels();
            yLabels.offsetX(0);
            yLabels.format(function() {
              return this.value.toFixed(vm_.currencySettings[vm_.selectedMarket].decimal);
            });

            console.log(chart.plot(0).yAxis().labels());

            // Horizontal Grid Lines.
            chart.plot(0).yGrid().enabled(true);
            chart.plot(0).yGrid().stroke('#ced4da', 1);

            // Enable current price indicator.
            var indicator = chart.plot(0).priceIndicator();
            // Set line settings.
            indicator.value('last-visible');
            indicator.fallingStroke('#ff6b6b');
            indicator.fallingLabel({background: '#ff6b6b'});
            indicator.risingStroke('#20c997');
            indicator.risingLabel({background: '#20c997'});
            indicator.label().fontColor('White');
            indicator.label().fontFamily('Roboto');

            // Initialize the volume bars.
            var volumeBars = chart.plot(0);
            var volume = volumeBars.column(volMapping).name('Volume');
            volume.zIndex(1);

            // Create and tune Y-Scale for volume bars.
            var extraYScale = anychart.scales.linear();
            extraYScale.maximum(highestVolume + (highestVolume * 4));
            extraYScale.minimum(lowestVolume);
            volume.yScale(extraYScale);

            // Enable Legend.
            var legend = chart.plot(0).legend();
            legend.enabled(false);
            // Set legend position.
            legend.positionMode('inside');
            // Style legend.
            legend.position('top');
            legend.align('left');
            legend.background().enabled(true);
            legend.background().fill('#fff', 0.87);
            legend.background().stroke('#ced4da', 1);
            legend.padding(8);
            legend.margin(8);
            legend.drag(true);

            // Set listener on the chart container.
            document.getElementById('chart-left').onclick = function(event) {
              mouseHoverHandler_(event);
            };

            // Event handler to get Y-Axis value on click.
            function mouseHoverHandler_(event) {
              // X click coordinate on plot.
              var y = event.offsetY;
              // Plot bounds related to chart container.
              var plotHeight = chart.plot(0).yAxis().getPixelBounds().height;
              // Plot left margin
              var plotTopoffset = chart.plot(0).yAxis().getPixelBounds().top;
              // Click on data area.
              if (y < plotTopoffset || y > plotTopoffset + plotHeight) {
                return;
              }

              // Get value of click related to yScale.
              var ratio = (y - plotTopoffset) / plotHeight;
              var value = (yScale.inverseTransform(1 - ratio)).toFixed(8);

              // Setting this value triggers watch which will build line.
              vm_.chartSelectedSwapRate = parseFloat(value);
            }

            // Customize the crosshair and yLabel.
            chart.crosshair(true);
            chart.crosshair().xLabel(false);
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().format(function() {
              return Number(this.value).toFixed(8);
            });
            chart.crosshair().xStroke(null);
            chart.crosshair().yStroke('#212529', 1);
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().fontColor('#fff');
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().fontSize(12);
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().padding(2);
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().hAlign('center');
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().width(78);
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().fontFamily('Roboto');
            chart.crosshair().yLabel().background({
              fill: '#212529',
              stroke: '#212529'
            });

            // Toggle the timeline scroller.
            chart.scroller().enabled(false);

            // Configure the visual settings of the falling candlesticks.
            candleSticks.fallingFill('#ff6b6b');
            candleSticks.fallingStroke('#ff6b6b', 1, '0', 'round');

            // Configure the visual settings of the rising candlesticks.
            candleSticks.risingFill('#20c997');
            candleSticks.risingStroke('#20c997', 1, '0', 'round');

            // Configure the visual settings of the volume bars.
            volume.normal().fill('#e9ecef');

            // Set the width of candlesticks and volume bars.
            chart.plot(0).pointWidth(6);

            // Toggle the default contextual menu.
            chart.contextMenu(false);

            // Enable the custom contextual menu.
            // var customContextMenu = anychart.ui.contextMenu();

            // Build the custom contextual menu.
            // (TODO)jberthelot: Connect these menu actions with the Go Long and Go Short sidebar
            //                   functions.

            // customContextMenu.attach(chart);
            // customContextMenu.itemsFormatter(function(items) {
            //   items = {
            //     'menu-item-1': {
            //       'text': 'Create a Long Cryptoswap',
            //       'action': function() {
            //         alert('You are going Long!');
            //       }
            //     },
            //     'menu-item-2': {
            //       'text': 'Create a Short Cryptoswap',
            //       'action': function() {
            //         alert('You are going Short!');
            //       }
            //     }
            //   };
            //   return items;
            // });

            // Add a custom class name to the contextual menu for easier styling.
            // customContextMenu.addClassName('custom-context-menu');

            // Set the candlestick chart container element.
            chart.container('chart-left');

            // Initiate the candlestick chart display.
            if (vm_.chart) {
              vm_.chart.dispose();
            }
            vm_.chart = chart;
            chart.draw();
          });
    }
```

Comment: Depends on the context where you're running this. If it's inside a scope and you're not debugging, the variable won't be acessible

Comment: @Phiter Scope only applies to variables, not properties. If it's not in scope he wouldn't be able to log `obj.R`, either.

Comment: Can you share your code, because it really depends on the context where you are trying to access the variable. It depends on which scope you are  trying to access obj.R and which scope you are trying to access obj.g

Comment: @Barmar, I tought so. I tought he could be running it in a different context.

Comment: @AalindSharma not sure how much you want me to send, but here's the actual console.log:  `console.log(chart.plot(0).yAxis().labels());`

Comment: I suspect it's a timing thing. You're probably trying to log `obj.g` before it's filled in. But if you do `console.log(obj)`, that's a live link to the object, so it gets updated as the object is modified.

Comment: It depends when you call the console.log,.  In chrome you will see the results of an async request for example if you logged the root object, but if you console.log a sub element that comes from an async request, it wons't..

Comment: An example. `var x = {}; console.log(x); x.y = "hello"`  If you run this inside the console, you will notice the object `{}`, but if you expand it it will be `{} y: "hello"`,  but when we console logged, the object didn't have the property `x`..  IOW: Chromes console is not a snapshot in time, it's a live view of the object,.. This can be very miss-leading sometimes.. You can also do `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`, if you wanted a snapshot, but this will only work for serialise-able objects.

Comment: @JoeBerthelot I would like to see the function/ snippet of code where your are trying to access the code.

Comment: @AalindSharma I've added the full function to the post, thank you

Comment: @JoeBerthelot i suspect the problem is with 'format' function just before the console.log. Can you try to check by putting console.log above that function ?

Comment: There is a lot going on after your console.log, IOW: other fields might have been filled in etc, try moving the console.log(obj.g) etc to the end of the function.

Comment: @Keith that it did..so simple.  Thank you sir!